# Help with Arrow Thickness

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need help with making the arrows thicker for the following:

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{\raisebox{11ex}{\tikz \draw[->] (0,0)--++(0.5,0);}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 1,name=box1,color=0.862745 0.0784314 0.235294]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
    \quad\myarrow\quad
    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 2,name=box2, color=0.196078 0.803922 0.196078]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}

 \end{Form}

 \end{document}
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: As in `\draw[->, line width=1mm]`?

Answer (score 21):

You can arbitrarily change the line width of the line by adding this to the options, like so:

```
\draw[->, line width=1mm] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

You can use any measurement system like points (`pt`), metric (`cm, mm`), inches (`in`) and so on.

Comment: But how do you draw an increasingly thick arrow?

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Alenanno's answer, you can use

```
\draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

or `very thick` or `ultra thick`.